# How to correctly handle laravel form?

Tags: php, laravel, crud, solid

I want to correctly handle user store form.

I consider which patter will be the most correct/popular. It is repository pattern? Service pattern?

Another difficulty:
User form: name, email, postal code, city, street. I want to create two models in one form: User and Address. How can I solve it? I throught about:

```
// UserController store(UserRequest $request)
$address = $addressRepo->create($request->validated());
$user = $userRepo->create($request->validated(), $address)
```

Issues i'm wondering about:

- UserRequest has data connected with user and address

I am confused as to what would be the most correct.

Comment: Hey did my answer work for you? If so do not forget to mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app won't be more than a CRUD, don't bother with repository pattern etc. Just use MVC pattern.

If you really need to use repository pattern you can use it also, dependency injection.

You can also create a UserService, which you send `$request->validated()` data to your service.

You should inject your repositories to this service. Your service should hold your logic, Repository should do store update etc.

Your contoller:

```
UserService::createUser($request->validated());
```

Your service:

```
...
$userRepository->createUser(...);
$addressRepository->createAddres(...);
```

Comment: The application is to handle complex crud operations (a lot of business logic). This is my first such large application. Is the repository-service pattern widely used these days?

Comment: Yeah ofcourse, especially you have so much business logic and duplicate code